# Better way to handle Uncaught Exceptions in ForkJoinPool Tasks/action

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7, java.util.concurrent, fork-join

What is the better way to handle exceptions(uncaught) while using [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) to submit tasks (`RecursiveAction` or `RecursiveTask`)?

ForkJoinPool accepts a [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to handle exceptions when the WorkerThread terminates abruptly(which is anyways not under our control) but this handler is not used when [`ForkJoinTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) throws an exception. I am using the standard [`submit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask%29)/[`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) way in my implementation.

Here is my scenario:

I have a Thread running in a infinite loop reading data from a 3rd party system. With in this Thread I submit Tasks to the `ForkJoinPool`

> ```
> new Thread() {
>       public void run() {
>          while (true) {
>              ForkJoinTask<Void> uselessReturn = 
>                    ForkJoinPool.submit(RecursiveActionTask);
>          }
>       }
>  }
> ```

I am using a RecursiveAction and in few scenarios a RecursiveTask. These tasks are submitted to FJPool using `submit()` method. 
I want to have a generic exception handler similar to `UncaughtExceptionHandler` where if a Task throws an unchecked/uncaught exception I can process the exception and re-submit the task if required. Handling the exception also ensures the queued tasks would not get cancelled if one/some of the Tasks throw an exception.

`invokeAll()` method returns a set of ForkJoinTasks but these Tasks are in a recursive block (each task invokes the `compute()` method and may be split further [hypothetical scenario] )

```
class RecursiveActionTask extends RecursiveAction {

    public void compute() {
       if <task.size() <= ACCEPTABLE_SIZE) {
          processTask() // this might throw an checked/unchecked exception
       } else {
          RecursiveActionTask[] splitTasks = splitTasks(tasks)
          RecursiveActionTasks returnedTasks = invokeAll(splitTasks);
          // the below code never executes as invokeAll submits the tasks to the pool 
          // and the flow never comes to the code below.
          // I am looking for some handling like this
          for (RecusiveActionTask task : returnedTasks) {
             if (task.isDone()) {
                task.getException() // handle this exception
             }
          }
       }
    }

}
```

I noticed that when 3-4 tasks fail the whole queue submission unit is discarded. Currently I have put a `try/catch` around processTask that I personally don't like. I am looking for more generic.

1. I also want to know about all the list of tasks that failed so that I can re-submit them
2. When the tasks throw exceptions do the threads get evicted from the pool (although my analysis found they doesn't [but not sure] )?
3. Calling `get()` method on the FutureTask would more likely put my flow sequential as it waits until the task completes.
4. I want to know the status of the Task only if it fails. I don't care when it completes (obviously doesn't want to wait an hour later)

Any ideas how to handle the exceptions in the above scenario?

Answer (score 2):

This is how we solved it in Akka:

```
/**
 * INTERNAL AKKA USAGE ONLY
 */
final class MailboxExecutionTask(mailbox: Mailbox) extends ForkJoinTask[Unit] {
  final override def setRawResult(u: Unit): Unit = ()
  final override def getRawResult(): Unit = ()
  final override def exec(): Boolean = try { mailbox.run; true } catch {
    case anything ⇒
      val t = Thread.currentThread
      t.getUncaughtExceptionHandler match {
        case null ⇒
        case some ⇒ some.uncaughtException(t, anything)
      }
      throw anything
  }
 }
```

Comment: I am stranger to AKKA, but if I understand correctly are you setting the exception thrown by your code to current threads exception handler? If so, will the thread be removed from the pool as the Threadpool executor may check this exception and mark the thread as bad thread. Can you explain..?

Answer (score 1):

@Rajendra, You are doing everything right, except you should use ForkJoinPool execute() instead of submit().

This way if the Runnable fails it will force a worker exception and it will be caught by your UncaughtExceptionHandler.

I don't know why this behavior exist but it will work! I've learned it the hard way :(

Taking from Java 8 code:
submit is using AdaptedRunnableAction().
execute is using RunnableExecuteAction() (see the **rethrow(ex)**).

```
 /**
 * Adaptor for Runnables without results
 */
static final class AdaptedRunnableAction extends ForkJoinTask<Void>
    implements RunnableFuture<Void> {
    final Runnable runnable;
    AdaptedRunnableAction(Runnable runnable) {
        if (runnable == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
    public final Void getRawResult() { return null; }
    public final void setRawResult(Void v) { }
    public final boolean exec() { runnable.run(); return true; }
    public final void run() { invoke(); }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5232453952276885070L;
}

/**
 * Adaptor for Runnables in which failure forces worker exception
 */
static final class RunnableExecuteAction extends ForkJoinTask<Void> {
    final Runnable runnable;
    RunnableExecuteAction(Runnable runnable) {
        if (runnable == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
    public final Void getRawResult() { return null; }
    public final void setRawResult(Void v) { }
    public final boolean exec() { runnable.run(); return true; }
    void internalPropagateException(Throwable ex) {
        rethrow(ex); // rethrow outside exec() catches.
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5232453952276885070L;
}
```